# How to get system time?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, systemtime

I want to get the current year, month, day, hour, minute second, and millisecond in javascript.

I am also using p5.js, if that has any helper methods.

This is what I want:

```
Year=2018

Month=4

Day=20

Hour=10

Minute=15

Second=25

Millisecond=236
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions like this are best answered by reading through [the P5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#group-IO).

Specifically, look at the **Time and Date** section, which lists exactly the functions you're looking for.

Comment: Oooh sorry, I thought that those returned values since the start of the program.

Comment: @mackycheese21 The `millis()` function does. But you can also google something like "JavaScript get milliseconds" for a ton of resources.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

This site has the link, courtesy of @tkausl.